How to extract the displacement eigenvectors from a phonon calculation?
I'm an undergraduate student using GPAW/ASE for research, and am currently working with the phonon module.  I can extract the modes, but aside from using phonopy I can't seem to find a way to get the displacement eigenvectors from the ASE phonon class.
How can I obtain the eigenvectors?
